# What does "frenzy gains effect of every rune" mean?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

A [legendary](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-undisputed-champion) dropped for me.

[image: Cropped screenshot of a tooltip for The Undisputed Champion]

What exactly does `Frenzy gains the effect of every rune` mean? Does it mean that no matter what rune I choose on Frenzy, it will get the effect of every other rune in the Frenzy skill?

Comment: _Offtopic_: do people really say "I dropped an item" when they _find_ an item in Diablo? I am not mocking anyone, I admit such lingos do and will always form, I'm just curious if it is widespread. I know people are saying "I defended an attack" instead of "I defended my base" in Starcraft...

Comment: Hmm. I think intuitively I thought this sentence in my native language and translated it mot-a-mot. That is the first time I interact with other people on English for Diablo, so I guess it was due to habbits :P I'll edit the question to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've seen "I dropped" before in the game chat though, so there are at least some people out there :-)

Comment: "I dropped" is not very common (in my experience), but people do use that phrase. Most people say "I looted" or "I got item x as a drop" or "Item x dropped". Again, that's only in my experience, and your experience may vary :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is exactly what it means. Your Frenzy will have the effect of *all* frenzy runes, no matter which rune you choose.
However, the element of the skill will be determined by your highest %elemental damage, so keep that in mind. (I can't find a specific quote for this belt, but it works that way for all other equips that grant all rune effects)

Comment: Even if we do not have all the runes unlocked?

Comment: I can't confirm it, since I have never found that belt before getting all runes, but it ***should*** give you the effect of all runes regardless if you have or haven't unlocked them.

Comment: "the element of the skill" = if I pick Maniac(fire damage) then Smite (Lightning) now does fire damage instead?

Comment: @Yorik Yes, that's how runes work for all skills. Rune element overrides the skill element.

Comment: Well, yeah for all runes that is true, but I am asking for clarification in the case of "all runes at once." I would *expect* each free rune effect to match the label on its box (in the absence of other info), but you suggest otherwise.

Comment: I did just look up some info and it seems that it has been changed to do use the element of your highest %elemental damage. I stand corrected.